# Create boxplot over lists from the first 6 header of the list

Tags: r, loops, data-visualization, boxplot

i am trying to create boxplots over 3 folders. each folders have 10 files in it. I have tryied to iterate the folders, but i have trouble in boxplotting each of the files.

So, here is my code

```
fileList = list.files(path=path,pattern="\\.teTestResult",full.names=T)
myfiles = lapply(fileList, read.delim,sep=";")
variablelist = c("BRFS3", "CPFE3", "CYRE3", "EMBR3", "ITUB4", "LREN3", "PETR4", "TIMP3", "TOTS3", "VALE5")
```

The `variablelist`is the name of the 10 files. 
I have stuck for now,
this is the example of boxploting 1 header in BRFS3 file. but i need 5 more iteration for this

```
boxplot(Return~gama, data=BRFS3)
```

Thank you so much for your help

```
    gama    theta   detectionsLimit NSMOOTH NREF    NOBS    sma lma PosTrades   NegTrades   Acc AvgWin  AvgLoss     Return
10.0    1.00    3            10     50  10  15  33  11  2       0.846154    0.0451529   -0.019449800    1.54942
1.0 1.00    5            5       80 40  15  33  7   2       0.777778    0.0676022   -0.008395400    1.54916
1.0 1.00    1           20       80 40  15  33  6   1       0.857143    0.0673241   -0.017465300    1.44823
```

The above is the sample of data file of variable BRFS3, i have tried to make it a good table to see, but i don't know how to show table in stackoverflow. Anyway i hope the table can help you understand the problem, 
Much thanks..

Comment: Can you provide a small example of your data (one file, or part of it)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes sir, i have add the part of the data there. i hope it can help, thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you use something akin to `dput()` for easy parsing into our R sessions?

Comment: Assuming you have a BRFS3, CPFE3 etc dataframe, you can try `for(i in variablelist){ boxplot(Return~gama, data=get(i))}`,

Comment: Maybe a better question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/. The Cross validated forum, more data enthusiasts there!

Comment: @CodePhobia thank you, i might try to get answer there.